# how did impala data duplicate happen

Tags: hive, hdfs, metadata, impala

I use the sql.shell to create a new table in impala .

It is my flow

1. Drop table if exists TR.test_tmp purge;
2. Create external table TR.test_tmp as select from (Select * from TR1.abc A join TR1.efg B on A.column1=B.column1 and A.column2=B.column2)
   location='/user/hive/warehouse/TR.db/test_tmp'
   TBLPROPERTIES ('external.table.purge'='true';
3. Drop table if exists TR.test purge;
4. Create external table TR.test as select * from TR.test_tmp
   location='/user/hive/warehouse/TR.db/test'
   TBLPROPERTIES ('external.table.purge'='true',;
5. Invalidate metadata TR.test;
6. Drop table if exists TR.test_tmp purge;

I call this sql.shell with TWS , when my shell is complete.

I check this data in impala, SELECT * FROM TR.test ;
sometimes I can find the old data in impala;

it data duplicate.

how did it happen ?
hdfs's data is not delete ?
or impala copy the data  as crate table ?

when I manual execution the sql
I select * from impala the data is not duplicate.

Comment: Most case its within milliseocnds. But it also depends on latency/network performance/some parameters that you can set while configuring Impala/hive. You can go through this link if you want to - https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/cm_bdr_hive_replication.html